# Saving Contact information to both Android and IOS from website

Tags: android, html, ios, css

Is there any way to save information entered on my website to a phone, the information is Name, number, all the information you would have to enter in order to create a contact on a phone. The code I need is for a button to save the information to the phone both for IOS and Android, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: you can save the information entered in your website on a database like mysql and then create APIs for your android/ios to send request and obtain those informations.

Comment: have you tried any thing .

Comment: Not yet I am rather new to this and was hoping that someone's insight will help steer me in the right direction I will do extensive research and try and come up with something.... hopefully something worth while. thanks for your input are you open to more questions as I work trough this........ Scotts